# Composerise Drupal command syntax and starting location

Tags: composer

I have 2 sites a dev site and the production site.  Need to convert them from drupal/drupal composer sites to the newer format allowing continued support for composer.
The syntax is unclear to me as detailed below. From https://github.com/grasmash/composerize-drupal

The '**composer-root**' is supposed to be where .git is.  Composer is at /home dir, their is a Git directory a .composer (dir) .gitconfig (file) (**I have always ran composer from terminal /opt/lampp/htdocs/d8/web directory**)
[image: location of composer]

So is composer-root=./home ??

The Drupal dev site is located in /opt/lampp/htdocs/d8/web where in the web dir the index.php, composer.json, composer.lock, update.php files are.  This is where I ran composer from previously.
[image: where I run composer from in terminal]

So is --drupal-root=./opt/lampp/htdocs/d8/web ??

**And I run the command from /opt/lampp/htdocs/d8/web as I have done previously?**

If correct: composer composerize-drupal --composer-root=./home --drupal-root=./opt/lampp/htdocs/d8/web --no-update

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I'm confused by your description of how the project directories are organized. Could you maybe post screenshots of the `ls -la` output of those directories?

Comment: pics of directory structure added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`composer-root` should not be your Home directory. It looks like you might have assumed that because there is a directory named `git` there, but that's not what the installation instructions at https://github.com/grasmash/composerize-drupal are referring to. Those instructions assume that your project files are being tracked as part of a Git repository. You can tell where the root of a Git repository is because it contains a directory called `.git` (note the dot in front, which the `git` directory in Home doesn't have).

If your project files are indeed part of a Git repository, the root would be in one of the upward directories from `/opt/lampp/htdocs/d8/web`.

> So is --drupal-root=./opt/lampp/htdocs/d8/web ??

Almost. The drupal root is where the `core` directory and `index.php` can be found. But that `.` in there makes this a relative directory path. You almost certainly mean to use an absolute path there, which would be `--drupal-root=/opt/lampp/htdocs/d8/web`.

> So is composer-root=./home ??

No. Most likely, you will want your `composer-root` to be one directory up from your project root (where index.php is). So I'd try `--composer-root=/opt/lampp/htdocs/d8`.